# What law requires Canadian and South African citizens to do a mathematical skill test when winning promotional gifts?

Tags: canada, gambling, lotteries, south-africa

In the terms and conditions of a keysight promotion to win an oscilloscope, I stumbled over the following sentence:

> In accordance with local laws, if the selected entrant is a Canadian or South African resident, that entrant will be required to answer a mathematical skill-testing question, without assistance of any kind (whether mechanical or otherwise), within the time frame provided above.

What is/are the law(s) behind this, and what is that law trying to achieve?

Comment: Interesting; only thing I can think of is that the math test is a form of captcha administered in a web browser by the company to screen out automated entries that happen to win.

Comment: Also applies in Australia.

Comment: @EJP: Yeah, probably in a lot of other countries too, the promotion was limited in countries, excluding australia

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From a [blog entry by Canadian lawyers](http://www.thompsoncoburn.com/news-and-information/sweepstakes-law-blog/blog/13-06-26/what-you-need-to-know-about-canadian-sweepstakes-and-contest-regulations.aspx) familiar with sweepstakes and contest laws:

> In Canada, games of pure chance are prohibited as illegal lotteries under our Criminal Code...
>
> For contests of chance, making prize redemption conditional on
>   answering a skill-testing question turns a game of pure chance into a
>   (legal) game of mixed chance and skill. Generally, a time-limited,
>   multi-step and multi-operational mathematical skill testing question,
>   answered without assistance, is sufficient.

That is under §206 of the [Criminal Code of Canada](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-46/page-49.html) - Offences in relation to lotteries and games of chance.

You will probably find similar statutes related to South Africa.

It's not uncommon to see "games of chance" turned into "games of skill" in order to avoid the creation of illegal lotteries.

Comment: Are there examples of such questions anywhere?

Comment: Given that in other areas (like taxes) often there are often quite some measures in place that prevent easy circumvention of laws by demanding hard proof I wonder if this practice is deliberately tolerated to allow for such promotional contests.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on this subject provides an example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skill_testing_question (Their example is (2 x 4) + (10 x 3). The answer is 38.) The article claims that a court decision ruled that a skill testing question had to have at least 3 operations.

Comment: Welcome to our illegal casin... errr I mean *dice throwing skill improvement center*.

Comment: @getoutofjailfreecard I saw your username, thought it was a part of your comment, and immediately thought monopoly ._.

Comment: Specifically, they're referring to [section 206 of the Criminal Code](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-46/page-49.html).

Comment: It's rather unfortunate that these laws make such games even more predatory on the poor and uneducated - even after winning there's a chance of having one's prize taken away.

Comment: @R..: In certain marketing areas they make such games so that you have to answer a question that basically everyone can answer, just so that you have a subconscious feeling of achieving something. Apparently that makes you far more likely to take part in such a game.

Comment: Bah, If you make an example of a mathematical three-operator question I say, make it (3 x 4)+(5 x 6) and be cool and froody about it.

Comment: 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 x 0 + 1 = ?

Comment: @Sobrique:  What answer would *you* give for your proposed skill-testing question?  The Windows Calculator says 5 or 1, depending on whether you're using Standard or Scientific View...

Comment: Google operator precedence - there is only one correct answer (5).